# How to load String Uri From Variabel Android

Tags: android, string, android-intent, maps

i have app for viewing maps list from listview,and i created intent for that,but i have no idea how to add latitude(koordinatlintang) and longitude(koordinatbujur) to this

`String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=latitude,longitude,place"`

here is my example code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        String koordinatLintang = b.getString("lintang");
        String[] koorlin = koordinatLintang.split(" : ");
        String koordinatBujur = b.getString("bujur");
        String[] koorbuj = koordinatBujur.split(" : ");

        lat = Double.parseDouble(koorlin[1]);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(koorbuj[1]);

        tanggal = b.getString("tanggal");
        jam = b.getString("jam");
        kekuatan = b.getString("kekuatan");
        kedalaman = b.getString("kedalaman");
        wilayah = b.getString("wilayah");

    } catch (Exception e) {}
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q="+"koordinatLintang"+"koordinatBujur"+"Place");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    try
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException innerEx)
        {
            Toast.makeText(PetaGempaActivity.this, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"` for `koordinatLintang` and `koordinatBujur` and add some `,`. Try this:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q="
                    +koordinatLintang
                    +","
                    +koordinatBujur
                    +","
                    +"Place");
```

Answer (score 0):

As I found link of [Google Maps Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

For more visit that link. Hope it will help you.